# Issues with creating candlestick chart using mplfinance

Tags: python, finance, yahoo-finance, mplfinance

Im relatively new to coding and especially financial coding and am having issues with mpl finance candlestick charts. My code goes something like

```
symbol = ['NIO']

start = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

Stockdata = yf.download(symbol,start,end)

fplt.plot(Stockdata,
          type='candle',
          title='NIO, 2016 - 2020',
          ylabel='Price ($)'
        )
```

My output looks like this:
[Looks more like a line graph than a candlestick graph](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HoY1P.png)

I've found multiple comprehensive codes to plot candlestick charts but this relatively simple one seems to work for others, however if it doesn't seem to work for me, I'm probably missing something simple but like I said am new to coding, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: what library are you using to plot the data? better to add a full example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It does look like a line chart, but it just looks collapsed because of the large number of data, but if you limit the number of data, it becomes a candlestick graph. The following is a graph with a narrowed-down count.

```
import yfinance as yf
import datetime
import mplfinance as mpf

symbol = ['NIO']

start = datetime.datetime(2016,1,1)
end = datetime.date.today()

Stockdata = yf.download(symbol,start,end)

mpf.plot(Stockdata[350:],
          type='candle',
          title='NIO, 2016 - 2020',
          ylabel='Price ($)',
         figratio=(12,4),
         volume=True
        )
```

[image]

Comment: out of curiosity what do the [350:] and figratio=(12,4) lines do?

Comment: [350:] is the data from the 350th to the end. figratio=(12,4) specifies the graph size. It is 12 inches wide by 4 inches high.